# Is there a way to define a TTL for an topic in spring-cloud-stream-pubsub?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, spring-cloud-stream, google-cloud-pubsub

We have some short lived messages about some data changes. I would like to limit the time, pubsub stores this messages to a few minutes or hours.

I found some settings for spring-cloud-stream-rabbitmq to set ttl  - but nothing for PubSub.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass various parameters that would suit your needs such as `--expiration-period`  or `--message-retention-duration` when you create a subscription with `gcloud beta pubsub subscriptions create`. You can check more [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/pubsub/subscriptions/create)